# How do I stop aging on played sims?

Tags: the-sims-4

So I'm writing a Sims 4 based story-slash-playthrough, but I would need to stop aging on a household that I have played. I know you can control aging on unplayed households, but I'm wondering if you can stop aging on a played household.

If that is not possible, then is it possible to revert a played household to an unplayed state without losing what was done with that sim?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Click the options menu in the top right, then Game Options (Second button down) then go to the Gameplay tab, and finally change Auto Age (Played Sims) to No.